# Method or data member not found MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wanted to run a function after 5 seconds so I tried doing:

```
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("05:00:00"), "myFunc"
```

However, I get method or data member not found error. I read the documentation for this there was no reference library I needed to add.

Comment: That is an Excel VBA method. Not in Access VBA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access - Pause Program Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105696/ms-access-pause-program-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for that for reuse. Use Sleep in it rather than DoEvents in cycle which eats up all the CPU.

```vb
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)

    Public Sub WaitSeconds(intSeconds As Integer)
      Dim dTime As Date
      dTime = DateAdd("s", intSeconds, Now)
      Do
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
      Loop Until Now >= dTime
    End Sub
```

Now you can call you function:

```vb
WaitSeconds 5
MyFunction
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737706/vba-sleep-doesnt-work

Comment: Sleep stops app + code execution, different to Excel, thats why you have to use a FormTimer..

Comment: @Andre: The link says: ".. it freezes the application.. " - this is what he wants. He wants to wait 5 seconds and then run the function - at least this is what I understood. I am using this function in several places in my application: like when an external exe does some work which takes some time (I am using pdftk.exe to merge 2 pdfs) and it works perfect. I do not think he wants to stop for 5 second, run a different code and return back. Access is not a multitasking application.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. You need to add the API `Sleep` declaration, or your code won't work.